# UIViewController variables persist after deallocation

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, ios10

I am attempting to write tests to check for retain cycles but came across this odd behavior. A `UIViewController`'s properties do not get deallocated when setting the view controller to `nil`. Take this mock object for example:

```
class BasicViewController: UIViewController {
   var someObject = NSObject()
   .....
}
```

All it has is a variable. You would assume that when calling `basicViewController = nil` would cause `someObject` to be nil, but its not.

```
it("releases someObject") {
  var controller: MockController? = MockController()
  weak var something = controller?.something
  expect(controller).toNot(beNil())
  controller = nil
  expect(controller).to(beNil())
  expect(something).to(beNil())
}

it("doesn't release someObject") {
  var controller: MockController? = MockController()
  weak var something = controller?.something
  expect(controller).toNot(beNil())
  _ = controller?.view
  controller = nil
  expect(controller).to(beNil())
  expect(something).toNot(beNil())
}
```

When calling `vc.view` this invokes `loadView` as well as the `UIViewController`'s life cycle functions - `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear`. My question is why? Why is it that when I reference a `UIViewController`'s `view` property, that all objects the `UIViewController` owns persists, even after setting the `UIViewController` to `nil`.

FWIW, I am using `Quick` and `Nimble` for testing, as well as `Swift 3.1`

Comment: But if you view the two tests, the only difference between the two is that I call _ = vc.view, which causes me to have to use toNot(), to make the test pass. Which is not desired. I created this example to show how even the simplest of objects cause this persistence to occur. There is no strong reference cycle happening, something is just an NSObject. It leads me to believe that when interacting with a view, it's controller's properties persist but are eventually deallocated after some time.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

Add an `autoreleasepool`, which will dictate precisely when objects are drained from the pool, and it works as you would have expected.

---

Long answer:

I'm experiencing the same behavior that you describe. But the problem isn't the properties of the view controller. It's the view controller itself.

In your examples, you're setting `controller` to `nil` and appear using the fact that it is now `nil` to infer whether the controller has been deallocated or not. But that's only testing whether that particular reference to the view controller is `nil`, but the view controller itself might not yet be deallocated. But you can use your `weak var` test with the view controller itself. Consider this view controller:

```
class BasicViewController: UIViewController {
    // this is intentionally blank
}
```

I can write tests where the view controller manifests the behavior that you describe, where that `XCTAssertNil` test after loading the view fails:

```
class MyApp2Tests: XCTestCase {

    func testWithoutView() {
        var controller: BasicViewController? = BasicViewController()
        weak var weakController = controller
        XCTAssertNotNil(weakController)
        controller = nil
        XCTAssertNil(weakController)          // this succeeds
    }

    func testWithView() {
        var controller: BasicViewController? = BasicViewController()
        weak var weakController = controller
        XCTAssertNotNil(weakController)
        controller?.loadViewIfNeeded()
        controller = nil
        XCTAssertNil(weakController)          // this fails
    }

}
```

But when I added an `autoreleasepool` to explicitly control when the pool is drained, it worked as expected:

```
func testWithViewAndAutoreleasePool() {
    weak var weakController: BasicViewController?
    autoreleasepool {
        var controller: BasicViewController? = BasicViewController()
        weakController = controller
        XCTAssertNotNil(weakController)
        controller?.loadViewIfNeeded()
        controller = nil
    }
    XCTAssertNil(weakController)          // this succeeds
}
```

BTW, if you're looking for additional confirmation on the timing of the deallocation of the view controller, itself, add a `print` statement in `deinit` (as well as where you set `controller = nil`) and you'll see that the timing of `deinit` changes in the presence of doing anything that loads the view.

I can't explain this behavior. Why should doing something with the `view` affect the view controller lifecycle? BTW, I also performed the above tests with properties of the view controller, like in your question, and I see the exact same behavior (but IMHO, that's unsurprising because it's just because the view controller itself hasn't been deallocated).

At least we can explicitly control the autorelease pool lifecycle timing with `autoreleasepool`.